# compiling iphone 3.1.3 with XCode 3.2.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, ios4

I just downloaded XCode 3.2.3 with iphone sdk 4, but I need to compile my app with 3.1.3, but there is no option in the project settings for that (just 4.0 or 3.2). Is there any other possibility for me besides downgrading to XCode 3.2.2??

Comment: What your'e seeing is the base SDK. You can chose 3.2 and as John says just change the deployment target to 3.1.3.

Comment: But if I set to 3.2 I am actually using the ipad simulator - How can I use the iphone simulator?

Comment: True but the OSs are almost identical in the sense of how they'll run your applications (with a few small exceptions). If you're looking for 'look & feel' differences nothing beats the device it's intended for. I use the iPad sim to test the functionality of certain things and to discover leaks but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Deployment section of the Build settings, there is an option to set iPhone OS Deployment Target. You can choose 3.1.3 from the list of available OS versions.

Comment: True, but he was asking about SDK, which != deployment target (though that's what some people mean, sometimes ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, you may choose any iPhone OS
>   Deployment target from the list. But
>   make sure that you are not using any
>   iPhone SDK 4.0 specific
>   methods/properties.

That is the catch, isn't it... is there an easy way to check that we're not doing any iOS4 SDK calls if we cant trap it during a compile?

I  found this (see the bottom of the page):

http://0xced.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-sdk-313-with-iphone-sdk-4.html

Unfortunately, it requires the following on the first step:

> "Locate iPhoneOS3.1.3.sdk and iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk from an iPhone SDK 3 installation"

And, of course I blew away my iPhone SDK 3 installation when I installed the iOS 4 SDK. So I'm kinda stuck.

Is there another alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my blog post with information on how to retrieve the iPhone SDK 3.1.3 from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may choose any iPhone OS Deployment target from the list. But make sure that you are not using any iPhone SDK 4.0 specific methods/properties.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385). SDKs other than 3.2 and 4.0 are no longer available for App Store submission.